# Do any editions of DnD have race/monster stats for Moggs?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, monsters, fantasy, races

I always liked including a variety of sub races or demographics for the major nations and races in my games.

I'd always wanted more variety to goblins; not goblin-oids (Bugbears/Hobgoblins) but plain vanilla goblins, and wanted to include [Moggs](http://mtg.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin#Mogg) (from Magic the Gathering).

Where could I find stats and background info for Moggs?

Comment: Oh, phew.  For a second there, I thought you'd mis-typed "Mog".  I don't think I want to be fighting Lone Star and Barf on my next encounter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Official statistics? No, prior to 3rd Edition and Wizards of the Coast's buyout of TSR, such a thing would have been instantly burned out of its papyrean existence by the sheer intensity of the fury it would have ignited at WotC Legal half-way across the country.

And after Wizards owned the D&D brand and system, they never (to my knowledge) crossed *Dungeons & Dragons* with *Magic: The Gathering*.

Comment: They were considering it for a bit, but it fell through due to how tightly the MtG crew wanted to control the IP.

Comment: Over nine years later, the last paragraph is no longer true! :)